# How add attribute in collection array in magento2 using plugin

Tags: magento2

```
public function aroundGetData(\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject, callable $proceed)
{
    // what is do here    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it feels that did not dive deep enough,

For global use easies way is to use `addField` or even alter SQL to add data from some related table.

```
public function aroundGetData(\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider $subject, callable $proceed)
{
    $subject->addField('field', 'alias'); // alias is optional
    $collection = $subject->getCollection(); // Here you have access to all public methods of collection.
    $select = $collection->getSelect(); // You can do whatever you want with Zend_DB_Select here
    return $proceed();    
}
```

`DataProvider` has `addField` and `addFilter` method uses `Product Collection` under the hood.